# What does || : mean in the shell?

Tags: shell

I'm looking at a shell script code and I don't know what is the purpose of the double-pipe (||) followed by colon (:), can someone explain? e.g.,

```
   $ <some_command> >/dev/null 2>&1 || :
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` is a boolean or.

`:` is a no-op command which does nothing and exits with a truthful status.

So, `anything || :` unconditionally returns true.

So, `some_command_that_may_fail ||:` will always succeed.

This is important if `set -e` or an ERR trap are in use, but you don't want your script to exit or raise an error if a command fails.

Comment: Wow, so this should be forbidden then :) this is worse than empty try-catch blocks. Thanks!

Comment: Why forbidden? Sometimes, you really don't care if a command fails. For instance, `grep` fails if it doesn't find a match, but you might not consider that a failure in your script, so `grep string file.txt || :` will prevent you script from exiting.

Comment: @theMarceloR, I wouldn't say worse -- it's very explicit on a line-by-line basis, and sometimes it's called for. If you're in error-handling code already sometimes you really want/need to fall through and continue your cleanup if part of it fails.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was just being facetious. Everybody has the right to do anything they want with their code depending on their objectives, although I believe that, for the case I'm seeing here (command to zip logs in case of a deployment failure), I'm not sure if I'm 100% ok with this approach. I mean, does the zip command fails that often? :)

Comment: zip can certainly fail. Files can be moved out from under it, files can be truncated, resized or deleted under it, its destination can run out of space... if this script is in source control, I'd suggest looking at who changed it when, and what ticket they attached to the change. If this was to make a failure silent when logrotate kicks in while zip is running... well, it wouldn't be a huge surprise.

Answer (score 2):

: colon is noop, the double pipe is the OR operation, so...

execute some_command OR (in case some_command fails) execute : (which is the no operation)

|| means execute the second only if the first command command fails. In this case the second command stands for "do nothing"

Comment: Not exactly "do nothing": set the exit status to "true"